# Map entries between two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data table `A` containing a set of entries and an `index` column that assigns a unique number to each row. I also have a data table `B` that contains entries of `A`, like so:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
A <- do.call(CJ, list(seq(3), seq(2), seq(2)))
A[,index := seq(nrow(A))]
B <- data.table(sample(3,3,replace=TRUE), sample(2,3,replace=TRUE),
                sample(2,3,replace=TRUE))
```

I want to define an `index` column for `B` that assigns each row to the corresponding index in `A`. What is the most efficient way to do this with `data.table`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do `A[B, on = names(B)]`

Comment: @akrun In my opinion, that's not an appropriate dupe. OP presumably wants to add a column to `B` by reference like `B[A, on=names(B), index := i.index ]`, not materialize an entirely new table. That's one of the big reasons folks use data.table.

Comment: @Frank I reopened it.  I thought it is a simple merge

Comment: Frank's answer is exactly what I was looking for. I would accept it as an answer if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a column from A to B based on their matching rows:

```
B[A, on=names(B), index := i.index ]
```

The main docs are at `?data.table`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a [join](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html):

```
A[B, on = c("V1", "V2", "V3")]

#   V1 V2 V3 index
#1:  1  2  2     4
#2:  2  1  2     6
#3:  2  2  2     8
```